# multiple (rasterVis) levelplots

Tags: r, levelplot, rastervis

i'm quite desperate trying to adjust two levelplots of one rasterstack each on one plot. It seems like `rasterVis::levelplot` does not take the `par(mfrow = c(...))` option for splitting the pane. An example using two rasterstacks that shall be arranged side by side on a new plot window :

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r1 <- stack(raster(f),log(raster(f)))
r2 <- stack(raster(f)-500,raster(f)+500)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  levelplot(r1)
  levelplot(r2)
```

Here, `levelplot(r1)` is being plotted on the full scale window, while `levelplot(r2)` unfortunately is painting over `levelplot(r1)`.

I tried to play around, wrapping the call for `levelplot` with the `print` function, which takes `split` as well as `newpage = false` options. Unfortunately I do not get the twist on how to use `split` properly so I end up with nothing but frustration.

I'd really appreciate your help, thanks in advance

Andi

Comment: `print(p1, split=c(1,1,1,2), more=TRUE); print(p2, split=c(1,2,1,2))`

Comment: @baptiste -- Nifty! I hadn't ever noticed that `split=` argument in `?print.trellis`.

Comment: In the FAQs: [How to print several Rasters with different legends in the same page](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#sec-8)

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán - just a heads up that at the FAQs, `print(p, split=c(col(m)[i], row(m)[i], 2, 2)` should probably read `print(p, split=c(col(m)[i], row(m)[i], ncol(m), nrow(m))`.

Comment: @jbaums You are right. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

For **grid**-based graphics, including those produced by **lattice** (which underlies **rasterVis**' plotting functions) the **gridExtra** function `grid.arrange()` does +/- the same thing as `par(mfcol=)` does for base R graphics.

```
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- levelplot(r1)
p2 <- levelplot(r2)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

**Edit:**  An alternative **lattice**-specific solution uses the `split=` argument to `print.trellis()`, the plotting method for lattice plots (h.t. baptiste & Oscar Perpiñán). `split=` takes a vector of four numbers. The vector's 3rd and 4th elements give the number of columns and rows in the display, while its 1st and 2nd elements give the column- and row-positions of the object being printed.

```
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- levelplot(r1)
p2 <- levelplot(r2)
print(p1, split=c(1,1,2,1), more=TRUE)
print(p2, split=c(2,1,2,1))
```

Comment: when using levelplot with the methods above (grid.arrange or print) to visualise a raster stack (2 rasters) next to a single raster, the single raster will be twice as big. How do i make them all the same size?