# How can I make multiplots for a SpatialPixelsDataFrame class object in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, raster, levelplot

I have a code similar to [one provided in a StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591240/spatial-interpolation-error-using-idw/39623736#39623736) using this answer from Ege Rubak, however I am doing an analysis over the year, so I have an image for each month of a specific year.

[image]

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)

lat <-  c(-23.49174, -23.49179, -23.49182, -23.49183, -23.49185, -23.49187)
long <- c(152.0718, 152.0718, 152.0717, 152.0717, 152.0717, 152.0717)
pH <- c(8.222411, 8.19931, 8.140428, 8.100752, 8.068141, 8.048852)
sample <- data.frame(lat, long, pH)

x.range <- range(sample$long)
y.range <- range(sample$lat)

x<-seq(x.range[1], x.range[2], length.out=20)
y<-seq(y.range[1], y.range[2], length.out=20)
grd<-expand.grid(x,y)

coordinates(sample) = ~long+lat
coordinates(grd) <- ~ Var1+Var2
gridded(grd) <- TRUE

proj4string(sample) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
proj4string(grd) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

dat.idw <- idw(formula=pH ~ 1, locations = sample, newdata = grd, idp = 2.0)
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]

plot(dat.idw, axes = T)
```

As in the image below, how can I merge the 12 images into a single plot and do something similar to a ggplot facet wrap?

[image]

Testing the code suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021889/multiple-rastervis-levelplots):

```
library(gridExtra)
library(raster)
s <- stack(raster(dat.idw))
s2 <- stack(raster(dat.idw))

p1 <- levelplot(s)
p2 <- levelplot(s2)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)

# Error in UseMethod("levelplot") : 
#  no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class 
# "c('RasterStack', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `levelplot` function from the `rasterVis` package by preparing a raster stack object and provide it to the function.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r1 <- raster(dat.idw)
r2 <- raster(dat.idw)

# I am only using two rasters as an example
# You can stack 12 rasters for your raster stack 
s <- stack(list(r1, r2))

rasterVis::levelplot(s)
```

[image]

Or use the `spplot` from the `sp` package.

```
sp::spplot(s)
```

[image]

Or the `tmap` package.

library(tmap)

```
tm_shape(s) +
  tm_raster()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. Could you tell me some good tutorial so I can edit this plot? I'll use levelplot (s) or spplot (s).

Comment: Please see this website for an introduction of the `rasterVis` package (https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/).